# Android studio и процессор amd

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня компьютер с процессором amd ryzen 7 2700 и я хочу установить на свой пк android studio, но когда уже установилась пытаюсь запустить emulator выдаёт такие ошибки:

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! 
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Установите genymotion для тестирования приложений.

Comment: @Bakhuss ПО ДРУГОМУ НИКАК?

Comment: С amd вроде бы нет. Андроид студио эмулятору нужна виртуализация интела.

Answer (score 4):

Имея Windows 10 Pro (1803 и выше), Android Studio (3.2 и выше), процессор AMD с виртуализацией SYM и установленную Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX), вы можете запустить встроенный эмулятор Android Studio. Производительность не будет сильно уступать использованию виртуализации VT-x от Intel.

Ссылка на habr с описанием: https://habr.com/ru/post/429610/

Обновленные требования к системе: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator

> The use of hardware acceleration has additional requirements on Windows and Linux:
>
> AMD processor on Windows: Android Studio 3.2 or higher and Windows 10 April 2018 >release or higher for Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) functionality

Answer (score 3):

Для АМД образы для эмулятора надо скачивать с вкладки "other images" и названием "armeabi".  Тогда эмулятор запустится, но будет жутко тормозить. genymotion вам в помощь.